# Get client id and client secret from Service connection in release step

Tags: azure-devops

In the Azure DevOps portal I created a Service connection for Azure RM. It works correctly. Now I want to get client Id and client secret in release step (by using PowerShell) when I'm authenticated with this Service connection. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the powershell script could help you  now? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here thus I could continue to help you:-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I stumbled into another issue, so I cant test your workaround

Comment: @Maxim Khon Any updates for below case? Could you post the issue you encountered? So that we can have a troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Get-AzureAdApplicationPasswordCredential cmdlet to get the password credential for an application.

Here is the offical documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0